# Comparing German specific letters in PHP does not work

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8

I've made a simple algorithm for detecting if a sentence is a isogram (word or phrase without a repeating letter). Algorithm is dead simple - it is just comparing every letter with each other.

```
<?php
function isIsogram(string $_s) : bool
{
    $_s = mb_strtoupper($_s, 'utf-8');

    $isogram = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($_s); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < mb_strlen($_s) - 1; $j++) {
            if ($_s[$i] == $_s[$j]) {
                $isogram = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return $isogram;
}
```

This works for every test case but test case with German letters:

```
public function testWorksWithGermanLetters()
{
    $this->assertTrue(isIsogram('Heizölrückstoßabdämpfung'));
}
```

Another algorithm (made by someone else) works fine:

```
<?php

function isIsogram($input)
{
    $input = preg_split('//u', preg_replace('/-| /', '', mb_strtolower($input)), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if(count(array_unique($input)) == count($input))
        return true;
        return false;
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an encoding Problem. The easy solution is to use `mb_substr` instead of the array notation.

```
function isIsogram(string $_s) : bool {
    $_s = mb_strtoupper($_s, 'utf-8');

    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($_s); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < mb_strlen($_s); $j++) {
            if (mb_substr($_s, $i, 1) == mb_substr($_s, $j, 1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Btw. you could break the loop, if you found the first matching string and in addition, you missed the last char (`-1` was wrong).